# Programmatically created spinner doesn't open

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, programmatically-created

I created a spinner programmatically:

```
ArrayAdapter<ServiceObject> medicineArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ServiceObject>(MedicineActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, medicines);
medicineArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MedicineActivity.this, getSpinnerAttrs(), 0);
spinner.setAdapter(medicineArrayAdapter);
spinner.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
buttonLayout.addView(spinner, index);
```

Where getSpinnerAttrs():

```
AttributeSet as = null;
Resources r = getResources();
XmlResourceParser parser = r.getLayout(R.layout.fragment_medicine);

int state = 0;
do {
    try {
        state = parser.next();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException xppe) {
        xppe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        if (parser.getName().equals("Spinner")) {
            as = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
            break;
        }
    }
} while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);

return as;
```

and Spinner in fragment_medicine is:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
    />
```

It shows normally But when I click on it, it doesn't open . . .

Comment: Can you check that if medicines array is empty or not?

Comment: @tasomaniac It's full, I can see it from  the selected item of the spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at the end I did it in another way.

I just added the attributes programmatically without reading them from an xml file as such:

```
spinner.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_dropdown);
```

And it worked perfectly.